# Prevalence meta-analysis with metafor - percentages instead of proportions

Tags: metafor

I'm running a meta-analysis of prevalence rates using the metafor package.
The dataset is named 'metaAAS' and it has the study's author/year, the number of participants exposed to the condition (ni) and the number of those presenting the symptom (nphy).

I'm using the following code to call the dataset from a csv file:

> metaAAS <- read.csv("metaAAS.csv")
> dat <- get(metaAAS)

Then I'm using the function 'escalc' to calculate effect sizes and outcome measures. I am using the argument 'PR' because the studies measure a dichotomous variable (either participants present the symptom or not):

> metaAAS <- escalc(measure="PR", xi=nphy, ni=ni, data=metaAAS, slab=paste (authors, year))

And this code to run the meta-analysis and show the results:

> res <- rma(yi, vi, data=metaAAS)
> res
> confint(res)

My model results show this:

**estimate: 0.3497**

se: 0.0352

zval:9.9428

pval:<.0001

ci.lb: 0.2807

ci.ub:0.4186

How can I **change the results to percentages** (e.g. 34.97) instead of proportions (0.3497)?
It would be easy just to change this in the description of the results, but the whole Forest Plot shows the estimated prevalence as proportions, and I need them as percentages.

Any thoughts? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I didn't manage to change the 'model results' output, but I changed the Forest Plot, which was the main goal.

First, create a function to multiply numbers *100:

> mytransf<-function(x)

> (x)*100

Then add this function to the forest plot arguments:

> forest (res, ylim=c(-1,28),transf=mytransf)